# why is max(dict1, key=dict1.values) wrong？

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, max

when I use python to find the largest value in dict, then return the corresponding key,

I know `max(dict1, key=dict1.get)` is right, I can get the key of largest value

but why is `max(dict1, key=dict1.values)` wrong？ it got `TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)`, why get is right but values is wrong?

Comment: Because [`dict1.get(key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) gives you the value for a given key, whereas `dict1.values(key)` doesn't make sense because [`dict1.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) provides a view of all values and doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: Is it because max function passes iterable to the function behind key, so the function behind key must can accept argument?

Comment: Yes: the key argument to max (and sorted, min, etc.) gets called once for each value in the iterable, *with* that value. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

Comment: Thank you very much! You help me a lot !!!